# Casbah/Salat: How to query a field that a part of a string is contained?

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah, salat

i try to write a query with Casbah and Salat to query a field that it includes parts of a name. 
I tried to use a regular expression like this (inside a SalatDAO):

```
val regexp = (""".*"""+serverName+""".*""").r
val query = "serverName" -> regexp
val result = find(MongoDBObject(query))
```

and with

```
val regexp = ".*"+serverName+".*"
```

The record is in MongoDB and when i search it with the complete name it works.

How is the right way to tell casbah to search for a part of the string ?

Another thing that i would like to fix is the string concatenation for the parameter. 
Is there any default way to escape input parameters with casbah, so the parameter is not 
interpreted as a javascript command ?

Best Regards, 
Oliver

Comment: Here is a part of my data that i query:
    case class Machine(_id: ObjectId = new ObjectId,
                       serverName: Option[String],

Comment: Ok. seems that i fixed it. 
    'val query = "serverName" -> regexp.r'

Comment: The next thing that i'm doing wrong is the query on a List with an regexp. Field is: `ips: List[String] = List[String](),`

If tried it with:
`val regexp = ".*" + parameter + ".*"
    val nameQ = "serverName" -> regexp.r
    val ipsQ = "ips" $elemMatch regexp.r
    val query = $or (("serverName" -> regexp.r), ("ips" $elemMatch regexp.r))`

But this breaks the signature with: `No implicit view available from scala.util.matching.Regex => com.mongodb.DBObject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mongodb shell you can find the server names contains the specific string by

```
db.collection.find({serverName:/whatever/i})
```

i dont have any experience with casbah, i believe it must be like this. please test

```
val regexp = ("""/"""+serverName+"""/i""").r  
find(MongoDBObject("serverName" -> regexp))
```

Comment: I think you do not need to provide the /es. For me it works now with `".*" + serverName + ".*"` and `val result = find(MongoDBObject("serverName" -> regexp.r))`